# Proper git remote tracking practice

Tags: git, github, permissions, tracking

The [GitHub forking documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) outlines that the best remote tracking practice for when you have your own fork is to have `origin` as your own branch and `upstream` as the branch that you forked from:

```
$ git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to *track* from the `upstream` branch so that I can see when I need to fetch code from the remote to rebase with my current version, but by default I would also like to *push* my code to the `origin` repository where I can make a pull-request to the repo I forked from (instead of attempting to push to the fork and getting a `Permission denied: 403` error).

Is there a "best" way to do this?

I couldn't find a definitive answer to this question after searching, please feel free to link me if this answer has been posted before and I just haven't found it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a potential interesting solution to this problem.

One thing I didn't really think about but just noticed were the `(fetch)` and `(push)` parentheses after a remote URL listing from the verbose  `git remote` command:

```
$ git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

What if you could have a single remote: `origin`, that has a different URL for fetch and push. That way you can track a default remote but push to a different one, also by default. I did some research and it turns out [this is very possible](http://sleepycoders.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/different-git-push-pullfetch-urls.html).

In the `.git/config` file you can keep the `fetch` and `url` parameters the same, but throw in an additional `pushurl` parameter for the forked (upstream) repository.

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
  pushurl = https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git
```

This leads to the following output:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_FORK.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
```

Which may not be good or proper practice but it certainly makes it much more cohesive. Would love to hear what you guys think of this!